# Homotopy of mappings of the circle into itself

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, logarithms

I'm trying to understand the proof of the proposition 2.4.1 from the book algebraic topology from a homotopical viewpoint on the page 15. But I don't understand why they use logarithm to define the phi function and why does alpha has to be on that interval, furthermore on which branches the function is bijective and why?

You can find the book here:

[http://files.gu.edu.ge:8008/Book/eleqtronuli%20wignebi/Matematika/literaturabakalavriati/Aguilar%20M.*%20Gitler%20S.*%20Prieto%20C.%20Algebraic%20topology%20from%20a%20homotopical%20viewpoint%20(UTX_%20Springer_%20.pdf](http://files.gu.edu.ge:8008/Book/eleqtronuli%20wignebi/Matematika/literaturabakalavriati/Aguilar%20M._%20Gitler%20S._%20Prieto%20C.%20Algebraic%20topology%20from%20a%20homotopical%20viewpoint%20(UTX_%20Springer_%20.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I think that they use logarithms because it takes $e^a$ to a, so it is a natural way to take $e^{ai}$ to ai. Which helps significantly with their proof.